# How can I search for multiple values from multiple columns?

Tags: dql

I need to search our Documentum/Oracle database for a list of values which may be present in a number of columns.

Listing them all out with OR statements seems to crash dqMan! There must be a better way of doing this... otherwise I'm going to have to search one column at a time.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  accession_no,
  object_name,
  title,
  subject,
  authors,
  keywords,
  resolution_label,
  owner_name,
  owner_permit,
  group_name,
  group_permit,
  world_permit,
  log_entry,
  acl_domain,
  acl_name,
  language_code,
  archive_notes,
  archive_status,
  pier_authors,
  pier_author_ids,
  compound_nos,
  identifiers,
  issued_on,
  pier_keywords,
  organization,
  preferred_terms,
  protocol_nos,
  source_database,
  pier_title,
  pier_doc_cnt,
  created_by,
  created_on,
  piera_item_type,
  piera_barcode,
  piera_container_no,
  piera_item_description,
  piera_location,
  piera_microfilm_location,
  piera_microfilm_no,
  piera_archive_site,
  pier_department,
  pier_viewurl,
  application_name,
  file_paths,
  alliance_names,
  dmr_content_fk,
FROM
  pier_record
WHERE
  archive_notes in  ('51156','51443','51762','51810','18030','50373','52453','51115','51651','50093','18220','18449','50048','51139','52179','52185','52439','52437','51439','51760','51756','51754','51457','51441','51437','51455','51435','51453','5144  5','50726','CCL1','BCL6','ERAP1','HUSH') OR
  compound_nos in   ('51156','51443','51762','51810','18030','50373','52453','51115','51651','50093','18220','18449','50048','51139','52179','52185','52439','52437','51439','51760','51756','51754','51457','51441','51437','51455','51435','51453','5144  5','50726','CCL1','BCL6','ERAP1','HUSH') OR
  identifiers in    ('51156','51443','51762','51810','18030','50373','52453','51115','51651','50093','18220','18449','50048','51139','52179','52185','52439','52437','51439','51760','51756','51754','51457','51441','51437','51455','51435','51453','5144  5','50726','CCL1','BCL6','ERAP1','HUSH') OR
  pier_keywords in  ('51156','51443','51762','51810','18030','50373','52453','51115','51651','50093','18220','18449','50048','51139','52179','52185','52439','52437','51439','51760','51756','51754','51457','51441','51437','51455','51435','51453','5144  5','50726','CCL1','BCL6','ERAP1','HUSH') OR
  organization in   ('51156','51443','51762','51810','18030','50373','52453','51115','51651','50093','18220','18449','50048','51139','52179','52185','52439','52437','51439','51760','51756','51754','51457','51441','51437','51455','51435','51453','5144  5','50726','CCL1','BCL6','ERAP1','HUSH') OR
  protocol_nos in   ('51156','51443','51762','51810','18030','50373','52453','51115','51651','50093','18220','18449','50048','51139','52179','52185','52439','52437','51439','51760','51756','51754','51457','51441','51437','51455','51435','51453','5144  5','50726','CCL1','BCL6','ERAP1','HUSH')
ENABLE
 (ROW_BASED)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you can use a common-table-expression (CTE) with DQL, but if you are searching multiple fields with the same values it might make sense here:

```
WITH cte_value_lookup (MyValue) AS (
    SELECT '51156' UNION ALL
    SELECT '51443' UNION ALL
    ...
    SELECT 'HUSH'
) 
SELECT DISTINCT
  accession_no,
  object_name,
  ...
  dmr_content_fk,
FROM
  pier_record
WHERE
  archive_notes in  (SELECT MyValue FROM cte_value_lookup) OR
  compound_nos in   (SELECT MyValue FROM cte_value_lookup) OR
  identifiers in    (SELECT MyValue FROM cte_value_lookup) OR
  pier_keywords in  (SELECT MyValue FROM cte_value_lookup) OR
  organization in   (SELECT MyValue FROM cte_value_lookup) OR
  protocol_nos in   (SELECT MyValue FROM cte_value_lookup)
ENABLE
 (ROW_BASED)
```

Not sure if that will speed things up but something to look into.

An alternative is to add indexes on those fields (archive_notes, compound_nos, etc.), but that is probably not ideal.